# Can anyone identify if this is a standard connector or not?

Tags: connector, lvds

Or let me know if there's a decision tree process to find out myself. It's from the LVDS connector on an apple motherboard. Foxconn part number m38&39, 01-01003047-00-b.

I'm wondering if the mounting bracket is a standard shape or model. It has a total of 30 pins, with 15 on each side facing out.

[image: The mount on the mobo]

The mobo mount

[image]

The actual part.

Comment: Digi-Key has a number of connectors that look similar to those. You should browse their catalog and check if there is one with the same number of pins (30, for the look of it), pin-to-pin distance (you need to take some measurements), etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called "board to board connector", or "btob connector". Try to add these words to your search efforts and you might be lucky. These kind of connectors are very hard to find anyway, and I'm not sure a standard exists for them.